# Compare two MySQL tables and combine maximum rows to a new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables using the following simple structure:

```
-----------
id | count|
-----------
```

One table for men and another for females. I'd like to compare the rows of the two tables and select the ones that have the highest count. For example:

If one row has a count of 500, and the other row has a count of 200, it should select the first row, and add it to a new table along with the results of the rest of the rows.

Comment: Try yourself with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName` ..its easy ...Good Luck!

Comment: I've tried various things, but can't quite wrap my head around it. The best I can come up with is something that combines all the rows into a new table and sorts them by id and then count, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: At stackoverflow you have to show your efforts at-least for this level of question. Try some web-search its very common problem.

Comment: Of course i have tried to search the web a lot before i posted the question here. It is not as simple as Select COUNT(*)... so a little more details would be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that table_a and table_b have identical id's:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (id, count)
SELECT table_a.id, GREATEST(table_a.count, table_b.count)
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.id = table_b.id
```

Comment: It works! Didn't knew the GREATEST() function in MySQL. Thanks a lot.